# Sockets in windows vs linux

Tags: sockets, network-programming

Are there differences in how Windows and Linux implements sockets? Is this a os concert or rather one entirely dependant on programming platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably their implementations are very different (Though it's hard to tell, as the windows source code isn't available.).

Both provides a rather similar API for programmers to use, based on the [BSD socket api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) , and the socket API for various programming languages are a wrapper around that native C API.